# Integration of jaxb2-maven-plugin with JUnit4

Tags: java, maven, junit4, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I am trying to execute a simple JUnit test in order to marshall/unmarshall some data.

Here is the definition of the 'data' :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "data")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Data {
 public Data(){}
 @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
 private String name = "name";
 public String getName(){return this.name;}
 public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}
}
```

The application works fine (I can marshall/unmarshall this object as XML)

But when I execute the test, I have the following error (the code in the test is exactly the same as it is in the application):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/istack/Pool
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1138)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.c42.asset.doubleface.data.Data.xml(Data.java:48)
at com.c42.asset.doubleface.data.MainTestXML.main(MainTestXML.java:68)
at com.c42.asset.doubleface.data.DataTest.setUpBeforeClass(DataTest.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.istack.Pool
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 30 more
```

I can't understand why the application works but not the test. I guess there is something about the plugin scope defined in maven. Here is my pom.xml :

```
<dependencies>      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mockit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
        <version>0.999</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>                 
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `jaxb2-maven-plugin` as dependency.

And you may have to add

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Ok .I removed "jaxb2-maven-plugin" dependency (only within the 'dependencies' tag), and I added the 'jaxb-core' dependency. It works good ! Even If I don't understand exactly why it works so good :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.istack</groupId>
    <artifactId>istack-commons-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.22</version>
</dependency>
```